# Filter a collection with another list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, filter

I have 2 lists, the first one is an event list
the second a list of id countries.

The event list contains a list of countries, so I am trying to filter the events that contain the countries that are sent in the parameter (list of countries).

I usually use foreachs for these cases, but I want to know if there is a way to filter these elements using lambda expressions?

This is my code using foreach

```
List<Event> finalList = new List<Event>();
 
 foreach (var eventItem in eventList)
    {
      foreach (var cItem in eventItem.CountrieList)
      {
        foreach (var pItem in countriesListParameter)
         {
           if (cItem .Id == pItem )
             {
                finalList.Add(eventItem )
             }

         }
      }

    }
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to understand your issue if you gave us some idea of the size of each collection (how may items in `eventList`, the typical size of an event's `CountrieList` and how big is `countriesListParameter`.  Are the `Id` of a `CountrieList` list and an item in `countriesListParameter` both just integers, or are they a more complicated type?

Answer (score 4):

With LINQ it looks so:

```
List<Event> finalEventList = eventList
    .Where(ev => ev.CountryList.Select(c => c.Id).Intersect(countriesListParameter).Any())
    .ToList();
```

So all events that have countries which `Id` is contained in the parameter-list.

You could also use `Contains`, but it is less efficient than `Intersect(..).Any()` if the lists are large:

```
List<Event> finalEventList = eventList
   .Where(ev => ev.CountryList.Any(c => countriesListParameter.Contains(c.Id)))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Depending on the sizes of the lists, it may pay off to first convert countriesListParameter to a set and then use contains (O(1))

Comment: @lgoncalves: Yes, that's also a good option, already if there are many events, because it's a one-time operation.